# Selection of points not showing on top (QGIS 2.2)

Tags: qgis

is there a way to bring the display of the selected objects on top? I have a large numer of points with a lot of them on top of eachother. When I make a selection through an expression and zoom to the selected points there is nothing to see. I have not found any option to bring the selected elements all the way to the top.

Setting the point symbolgy to "exploding" display does not help here either.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **Query** builder to only show objects you include in the filter:

*Layer* > *Query...*

[image: Query 1]

[image: Query 2]

Comment: Thank you Joseph. However this does not solve my problem. Following your example: if I set up a query (ID = 4 in your case) and if I have two or more points on top of eachother (with ID = 4 and with the same coordinates) I cannot see them. If I open the attribute table and select a feature, the selection won't show in the map because the point feature is covered by another point feature.

Comment: Does your layer not contain any unique attributes for your points?

Comment: Yes it does. However I am not querying the ID. This is my use case: selection / query of attributes in the table (names of species) and the corresponding map display of the point with the color of a selection. Basically show me all of species A, of species B, etc. If you have more than one point on the same location the selection is hidden.

Comment: Thank you Lombardi, other than querying exactly the attributes ("Species A" AND "X Coord" AND "Y Coord") or going through a _Rule-based Styling_ and setting the filters and Rendering order, I don't think there's much else you can do. Unless I missed something, in which case hopefully others can advise.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I figured I am missing something. ArcMap is doing this the "right" / wished for way: if you select a point which is covered by another on the same location, it "brings" the selected point to the top / makes the selection visible.